# Change to directory using variable name

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory

I've written a script to search for a shape file (.shp), I want to change to that directory once found: Here's what I have

```
 FOR /F %%X IN ('DIR /S /B *.shp') DO SET shapefolder=%%~DPNX
 IF DEFINED shapefolder (
 ECHO %shapefolder%
 CD /d shapefolder REM doesn't work
 ) ELSE (
 ECHO File not found
 )
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are wrong with your code. The first, as Oliver already pointed out, is that `cd /d shapefolder` should be `cd /d %shapefolder%` so that  you're calling the actual variable.

The other thing is that `SET shapefolder=%%~DPNX` should be`SET shapefolder=%%~DPX` instead.

This is because the `N` refers to the filename of the file it finds, so if you have a square.shp, your code currently will look for `C:\files\shapes\square` instead of `C:\files\shapes\` like it's supposed to.

Comment: cd \d %shapefolder% ?? Are you sure you don't mean cd '/d %shapefolder%

Answer (score 0):

Just add the percent sign to your variable in the `cd` command:

```
CD /d %shapefolder%
```